# Tried everything I found on stack but nothing worked to modify my array php

Tags: php, arrays

I can't modify an array no matter what I do and I tried everything I found on stack without success. I have no error message and the array just doesn't change.

I have an array containing smaller arrays

```
$a=array('Champagne 1er Cru Le Cran Domaine Bereche 2010');
$b=array('Champagne 1er Cru Le Cran Domaine Bereche 2011 Magnum');
$c=array('Champagne 1er Cru Extra Brut Bulle de Rose Domaine Savart NV');
$d=array('Champagne 1er Cru Le Cran Domaine Bereche 2010 Magnum');
$e=array('Champagne 1er Cru Monts Fournois Domaine Bereche 2012');
$f=array('Champagne 1er Cru Brut Expression Nature Domaine Savart 2014');
$g=array('Champagne 1er Cru Le Cran Domaine Bereche 2009');  
  
$array=array($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g);
```

Here's the code

```
foreach($array as $element) {
    uasort($array, 'sort_by_name');

function sort_by_name($a, $b)
{
        return strcmp($a[0], $b[0]);
}
```

and the order of the arrays doesn't change at all. And the array is declared in the same function.

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Why are you using multidimentional array when a single array would be enough? You have only 1 element in each subarray

Comment: It's just an example, the real arrays contain more than one info and I got to sort them by name

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$a=array('Champagne 1er Cru Le Cran Domaine Bereche 2010');
$b=array('Champagne 1er Cru Le Cran Domaine Bereche 2011 Magnum');
$c=array('Champagne 1er Cru Extra Brut Bulle de Rose Domaine Savart NV');
$d=array('Champagne 1er Cru Le Cran Domaine Bereche 2010 Magnum');
$e=array('Champagne 1er Cru Monts Fournois Domaine Bereche 2012');
$f=array('Champagne 1er Cru Brut Expression Nature Domaine Savart 2014');
$g=array('Champagne 1er Cru Le Cran Domaine Bereche 2009');  
  
$array=array($a, $b, $c, $d, $e, $f, $g);



function sort_subregion($a, $b)
{
        return strcmp($a[0], $b[0]);
}

uasort($array, 'sort_subregion');

print_r($array);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => Champagne 1er Cru Brut Expression Nature Domaine Savart 2014
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Champagne 1er Cru Extra Brut Bulle de Rose Domaine Savart NV
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => Champagne 1er Cru Le Cran Domaine Bereche 2009
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Champagne 1er Cru Le Cran Domaine Bereche 2010
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Champagne 1er Cru Le Cran Domaine Bereche 2010 Magnum
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Champagne 1er Cru Le Cran Domaine Bereche 2011 Magnum
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Champagne 1er Cru Monts Fournois Domaine Bereche 2012
        )

)
```

Comment: Wait... That's actually exactly what I sent... but in a different order which will have absolutely no effect

Comment: @R-son you're looping and I'm not. Also you used the wrong function in uasort. `uasort($array, 'sort_subregion');` vs `uasort($array, 'sort_by_name')`

Comment: actually, I just typed it wrong in the example I made but in the actual function I didn't type it wrong. Thanks for telling me tho cause I didn't notice

Comment: It didn't work. But I remade my whole program. I think the fact that I was sorting it multiple times made it bug so I sorted everything in one usort and now it's good